# Memory allocation in C++: Dynamic vs Static

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, memory-management, c++17, theory

I read on GeeksforGeeks that arrays in C++ are statically allocated memory i.e. at the compile time.
Whereas Vectors in C++ are allocated memory dynamically.

```
E.g. 
vector<int> vec;
vec.push_back(1);
```

But I have some doubt in this.
Like if I declare array like :->

```
int n;
cin>>n;
int arr[n];
```

How can this be statically allocated because at runtime only we will provide the value for n and then only memory will get allocated. Shouldn’t this come under dynamic allocation?

Comment: [`int arr[n];` in this example is not standard C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/), but it is indeed allocated dynamically at runtime, however NOT in dynamic memory (like `new[]` does), but rather in the current stack frame instead, so it gets freed automatically when it goes out of scope, like any other local automatic variable. GfG is talking about fixed-sized arrays that specify their size at compile-time, ie `int arr[123];` or `const int n = 123; int arr[n];`

Comment: Huh. Normally when a problem starts with something like *I read on GeeksforGeeks ...* we spend the next page or two explaining why GeeksforGeeks is wrong. This time it's the opposite. Is this a sign of the glorious trend upward or just an example of a stopped clock being right twice a day? Only time will tell.